# SimpleDateFormat + java.sql.Timestamp in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, sql, timezone, jasper-reports, timestamp

I have a timezone-delicate report in Jasper and I can't really seem to figure out how to show a few dates relative to a timezone.

I have a view which returns dates with the following format:

"2015-03-02 11:45:00+01"

"2015-03-02 23:59:59+01"

"2015-03-03 00:00:00+01"

"2015-03-03 08:00:00+01"

"2015-03-03 09:20:00+01"

"2015-03-03 11:00:00+01"

"2015-03-03 09:00:00+01"

"2015-03-03 09:30:00+01"

etc (notice the +01 at the end)

In my report, I have:

new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", $P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($F{start_date});

However, for example, for "2015-03-02 11:45:00+01" I don't get 12:45 shown, I get 11:45.

Also, I need to sum-up the hours (they're intervals) and this gives me a 1hr (in this case) error.

Can anyone help me show the correct hour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` takes a `Date`, not a `Calendar` - which means it can't be provided the time zone in the value itself.

Assuming you need to stick with `SimpleDateFormat` (rather than using Joda Time or Java 8's `java.time`, for example) then you'll need to set the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` itself. If you need to take the time zone from the data (rather than having a report-wide zone) then you'll need to call `setTimeZone` before formatting each value - but of course, you'll *also* need to make sure you've got the time zone in the value, and `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't have any notion of a time zone, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Can you please an example of this?

Comment: @PratikRawlekar: Of what, exactly? Note that I'd strongly advise you to use `java.time` if at all possible anyway.